# How to wrap a widget function with consumer and set it's onPressed function using provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management

I'm new to flutter and I'm learning provider. My app is about making many buttons every button changes the color of the something specific in the application ui(app bar, background, drawer, etc..). So to make the code easier i should make a button widget function like this:

```
Widget colorButton( Color c){
  return RaisedButton(
    onPressed: (){},
    color: c,
  );
}
```

But i noticed that i can't assign an onPressed function when i call this button to change the color of anything. So (I dont know if this is the best way to do this or there is another way) I changed the function to be:

```
Widget colorButton( Color c, Function f){
  return RaisedButton(
    onPressed: (){f();},
    color: c,
  );
}
```

Then i pass a function of the model i made earlier in the model like so:

```
class bG_Vairables extends ChangeNotifier{
  Color bG;
  Function setBG(Color c){
    bG = c;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I make instance like this:

```
Consumer<bG_Vairables>(builder: (context, v, child){
                            return colorButton(Color.fromRGBO(240, 230, 255,1) , v.setBG(Color.fromRGBO(240, 230, 255,1)));
                          },
                        ),
```

But i get this error:

````
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer<bG_Vairables>(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<bG_Vairables> above this Consumer<bG_Vairables> Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer<bG_Vairables> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<bG_Vairables>.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediatly.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Consumer<bG_Vairables> file:///C:/Users/Mu'men/AndroidStudioProjects/provider_project/lib/main.dart:46:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:269:7)
#1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:221:30)
#2      Consumer.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:177:16)
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:260:41)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:28)
...
````

Comment: Where did you create the ChangeNotifierProvider? The consumer needs that Provider above in the tree

Comment: In the main like this:
`void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => appBarVairables()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => bG_Vairables()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}`

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that the Consumer is not build inside the build method but created somewhere else (you said you make an instance of consumer) so the context is not really the same, can you post how do you use it inside your widgets?

Answer (score 0):

You must add `ChangeNotifierProvider` somewhere on the ancestor of widget where `colorButton()` is written.

For e.g.

Currently if you are getting to colorButton()'s StatefulWidget page (lets name it ColorButtonPage) like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>ColorButtonPage()))
```

Change it to this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>ChangeNotifierProvider(create:(context)=> bG_Vairables(), child: ColorButtonPage(), ),),)
```

This way, Consumer will be able to find bG_Vairables object.